# Solving a reaction diffusion dystem

Tags: differential-equations, broken-code

I have a problem solving a numerical reaction diffusion equation. It emits the following message:

> RecursionLimit::reclim2: "Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation

How can I solve this problem? My PC is quite fast, and I am willing to run it over night if necessary. But first of course I want to check if my equations are all right. How can I figure out working parameters and boundary conditions?

Here is the code (Derived from an old Maple code of mine and a code I found here in the *Mathematica* Stack Exchange):

```
ClearAll;

(*Parameter*)

da = 1;
db = 0.1;
k = 10;

(*Gleichungssytem und NDSolve*)

a1 = {D[a1[t, x, y], t] == 
    da*D[a1[t, x, y], x, x] + da*D[a1[t, x, y], y, y] - k*a1[t, x, y]};

a2 = {D[a2[t, x, y], t] == 
    db*D[a2[t, x, y], x, x] + db*D[a2[t, x, y], y, y] - k*a2[t, x, y]};

a3 = {D[a3[t, x, y], t] == 
    da*D[a3[t, x, y], x, x] + da*D[a3[t, x, y], y, y] + 
     k*a3[t, x, y](*-D[a4[t,x,y]]*)};

Ω = ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= 100 && 0 <= y <= 100, {x, y}];

(*Lösung des Gleichungssystems*)
soln = NDSolve[{a1, a2, a3, (*a4*)},

  Derivative[0, 1, 0][a1][t, 0, y] == 0,
  Derivative[0, 1, 0][a1][t, 100, y] == 0,
  Derivative[0, 0, 1][a1][t, x, 0] == 0,
  Derivative[0, 0, 1][a1][t, x, 100] == 0,
  a1[0, x, y] == 100, a1, {x, 0, 100}, {y, 0, 100}, {t, 0, 10},


  Derivative[0, 1, 0][a2][t, 0, y] == 0,
  Derivative[0, 1, 0][a2][t, 100, y] == 0,
  Derivative[0, 0, 1][a2][t, x, 0] == 0,
  Derivative[0, 0, 1][a2][t, x, 100] == 0,
  a2[0, x, y] == 0, a2, {x, 0, 100}, {y, 0, 100}, {t, 0, 10},


  Derivative[0, 1, 0][a3][t, 0, y] == 0,
  Derivative[0, 1, 0][a3][t, 100, y] == 0,
  Derivative[0, 0, 1][a3][t, x, 0] == 0,
  Derivative[0, 0, 1][a3][t, x, 100] == 0,
  a3[0, x, y] == 0, a3, {x, 0, 100}, {y, 0, 100}, {t, 0, 10},

(*Plotausgabe a1*)
Plot3D[a1[t, x, 1] /. soln, {t, 0, 10}, {x, 0, 100}, PlotStyle -> Gray]


(*Plotausgabe a2*)
Plot3D[a2[t, x, 1] /. soln, {t, 0, 10}, {x, 0, 100}, PlotStyle -> Pink]


(*Plotausgabe a3*)
Plot3D[a3[t, x, 1] /. soln, {t, 0, 10}, {x, 0, 100}, PlotStyle -> Green]
```

Comment: You have `a1` in both the left and right sides of `a1 = {D[a1[t, x, y], t] == daD[a1[t, x, y], x, x] + daD[a1[t, x, y], y, y] - k*a1[t, x, y]};` and similarly for the other equations. Use different variables on the left and the right and try again.

Comment: Your definition of the equations define `a1`, etc., and include `a1` in them, hence the recursion.  Call the equation something else, like `eqna1`.

Comment: First, if you carefully insert 4 spaces in front of every line, even the blank lines, of your code above then that will keep SE from "desktop pubishing"="eating" some of your code. Second, you have defined a1=list containing a derivative while at the same time telling Mathematica that a1 is the function you want to solve for. That is where your recursion errors are coming from. Third, you only have one NDSolve, but it looks like you have three different sets of initial conditions. Fourth, there is no ending ] for the NDSolve. Fifth, the CapitalOmega doesn't seem to be used. Fix those first.

Comment: Can you give a link to the sources of your code, or what you have in mind? A theoretical explanation would also help a lot!

Comment: Your `NDSolve` expression is ill-formed. It doe not have the correct Mathematica syntax for solving a system of ODEs.

Comment: `ClearAll;` does nothing. It is not a command (Mathematica does not have commands). Try ``Clear["Global`*"]``

Answer (score 6):

Correcting the formatting yields a result without errors. You'll have to evaluate if the solution is reasonable.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

(*Parameter*)

da = 1;
db = 0.1;
k = 10;

(*Gleichungssytem und NDSolve*)

eqa1 = {D[a1[t, x, y], t] == 
    da*D[a1[t, x, y], x, x] + da*D[a1[t, x, y], y, y] - k*a1[t, x, y]};

eqa2 = {D[a2[t, x, y], t] == 
    db*D[a2[t, x, y], x, x] + db*D[a2[t, x, y], y, y] - k*a2[t, x, y]};

eqa3 = {D[a3[t, x, y], t] == 
    da*D[a3[t, x, y], x, x] + da*D[a3[t, x, y], y, y] + 
     k*a3[t, x, y](*-D[a4[t,x,y]]*)};
```

Fixed [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html)

```
(*Lösung des Gleichungssystems*)
soln = NDSolve[{eqa1, eqa2, eqa3,(*a4,*)
   Derivative[0, 1, 0][a1][t, 0, y] == 0,
   Derivative[0, 1, 0][a1][t, 100, y] == 0,
   Derivative[0, 0, 1][a1][t, x, 0] == 0,
   Derivative[0, 0, 1][a1][t, x, 100] == 0,
   a1[0, x, y] == 100,
   Derivative[0, 1, 0][a2][t, 0, y] == 0,
   Derivative[0, 1, 0][a2][t, 100, y] == 0,
   Derivative[0, 0, 1][a2][t, x, 0] == 0,
   Derivative[0, 0, 1][a2][t, x, 100] == 0,
   a2[0, x, y] == 0,
   Derivative[0, 1, 0][a3][t, 0, y] == 0,
   Derivative[0, 1, 0][a3][t, 100, y] == 0,
   Derivative[0, 0, 1][a3][t, x, 0] == 0,
   Derivative[0, 0, 1][a3][t, x, 100] == 0,
   a3[0, x, y] == 0},
  {a1, a2, a3}, {x, 0, 100}, {y, 0, 100}, {t, 0, 10}]

(*Plotausgabe a1*)
Plot3D[a1[t, x, 1] /. soln, {t, 0, 10}, {x, 0, 100}, PlotStyle -> Gray]
(*Plotausgabe a2*) 
Plot3D[a2[t, x, 1] /. soln, {t, 0, 10}, {x, 0, 100}, PlotStyle -> Pink]
(*Plotausgabe a3*) 
Plot3D[a3[t, x, 1] /. soln, {t, 0, 10}, {x, 0, 100}, PlotStyle -> Green]
```

A1 Plot:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Since your "system" consists of three independent ODEs, they can be tackled one at a time. Here is how to solve the 1st one. It takes but a fraction of a second.

```
da = 1;
db = 0.1;
k = 10;
eq1 = 
  D[a1[t, x, y], t] == da D[a1[t, x, y], x, x] + da D[a1[t, x, y], y, y] - 
    k a1[t, x, y];
s1 = 
  NDSolve[{eq1,
    Derivative[0, 1, 0][a1][t, 0, y] == 0, 
    Derivative[0, 1, 0][a1][t, 100, y] == 0, 
    Derivative[0, 0, 1][a1][t, x, 0] == 0, 
    Derivative[0, 0, 1][a1][t, x, 100] == 0, a1[0, x, y] == 100},
    a1, {x, 0, 100}, {y, 0, 100}, {t, 0, 10}]

Plot3D[a1[t, x, 1] /. s1, {t, 0, 10}, {x, 0, 100}, PlotStyle -> Gray]
```

[image: plot]